# How to use IntelliJ with Play Framework and Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea

I am trying to use IntelliJ with a play framework 2.11 application.

I installed the Play Framework 2 plugin and the Scala plugin for IntelliJ.

I created a Play application.  I have been struggling writing and running Specs 2 tests in IntelliJ.  My run config says to run "make" first when running the Specs 2 test, however it doesn't look like my test classes are being generated.  Keeps on telling me that it could not find the specification.  When I look on the file system, there is no code in target/test-classes, the directory is empty.  Further, it seems to take a LONG time to do the build, at least compared to running the Play console.

I wanted to see how people are using Play with IntelliJ.  Do you just use IntelliJ as an editor, and run everything through the Play console?

Is there a way whereby you can run your Application tests in IntelliJ (getting your test classes to run)?

I have never had any problem running the Play console and running ~test-only test=xxx.Spec.  It has typically been rather fast.

Here is the exception I am getting in IntelliJ when I try to run my Specs2 tests:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.runSingleTest(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.main(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not create specification: test.ApplicationSpec
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecification(BaseSpecification.scala:96)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.createSpecification(ClassRunner.scala:64)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.start(ClassRunner.scala:35)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.main(ClassRunner.scala:28)
    at org.specs2.runner.NotifierRunner.main(NotifierRunner.scala:24)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Update**: In newer versions if IntelliJ IDEA, it is no longer necessary to create the module from play/activator. IntelliJ IDEA has now a really good support for SBT projects. If exists, delete all the idea related directories inside your project. Then in IntelliJ IDEA click File -> Open and choose your build.sbt file. That's all.

---

IntelliJ IDEA has a good integration for the Play Framework 2. Sometimes it jams, but most of the time it runs. I use it to run(single, all) tests, start or debug the play application and edit my code (o; And this all from within the IDE and without the sbt console.

Here is a short tutorial with the most important steps. Currently I use IntelliJ IDEA 12.1 with the newest Play Framework 2 and Scala plugins.

**1. Create a new application**

```
play new myapp
```

**2. Create the IDE module**

Start the play console:

```
cd newapp
play
```

Create the module:

```
idea with-sources=yes
exit
```

**3. Configure the IDE**

1. Open the newly created project
2. Open the module settings(select project and press F4)
3. Add the Scala library to your project

   1. Select *Modules->myapp->Dependencies*
   2. Press the plus Icon and select Library(2)
   3. Add the Scala 2.10.0 Project Library
4. Select the Compiler Library in the Scala Facet

   1. Select *Facets->Scala(myapp)*
   2. Set the *Compiler library* to Scala 2.10.0
5. Fix the errors

   1. Select *Modules->myapp-build->Dependencies->scala-2.9.2* and press the minus icon
   2. Select *Libraries->Scala 2.9.2* and press the minus icon
6. Fix the output Path for the *myapp-build* module

   1. Select *Modules->myapp-build->Paths*
   2. Append *classes* to the *Output path*(X:\projects\myapp\project\target\scala_2.9.2\classes)
   3. Append *test-classes* to the *Test output path*(X:\projects\myapp\project\target\scala_2.9.2\test-classes)

**4. Run a test**

Select the *ApplicationSpec* under the test directory and click *Run 'ApplicationSpec'* from the context menu. You should get an error that the compiled template could not be found. This is because the IDE doesn't compile the templates, but this can be done by run the application once. Also follow point 5 and then run the test again.

**5. Run the application**

Select a controller and click *Run Play 2 App* from context menu. This should start the application on address: `http://localhost:9000/`.

**6. Update dependencies**

If you update your application dependencies then you must tell the IDE about this changes. Also after running the *play update* command you must close the IDE and remove some files from project directory. If you execute the `play idea` command before removing the files, you get double dependencies in your play project.

Execute the following steps to update your dependencies:

1. Run the `update` task from your play console
2. Remove the *`.idea_modules`* and *`.idea/libraries`* directories
3. Run the `idea with-sources=yes` command in the play console
4. Run step 3 again

Comment: So far this works!  Thanks a ton for the info!  I have one sticking question, when you run a test, it loads the project information and everything, which takes a long time.  Is there any way to run the tests faster?  My guess is that it takes so long because it runs "Make" before launching the test.  Any pointers?

Comment: One other question, it looks like the idea plugin generates a bunch of XML files that hard code the classes to wherever Play is installed.  I guess if more than one person is working on the project, you need to make sure that everyone has play installed in the same file path?

Comment: So far so good my friend.  To avoid the long compile times when running tests, I start up the SBT Console in IntelliJ and run ~test:compile.  Then, every time I make a code change code is recompiled QUICKLY, whether that is app code or test code.  In my Run Configuration, I remove the "Make" before launch on the tests.  This is very fast when doing BDD / TDD.  1 million thank yous for the answer!!!!

Comment: You can switch to the internal compiler to improve the runtime of the tests. But sometimes this causes some issues in some versions of the scala plugin. Then you must recompile the complete project and run the tests again. You must uncheck the setting *Use external build* under *Settings->Project Settings->Compiler*, to switch to the internal compiler. To your other question. I think it's a bad practice to commit the IDE settings to the VCS.

Comment: Thanks again.  I agree, I was going to add .idea* to .gitignore.

Comment: This is just an update to this answer.  On my mac, I had issues with the source files being found when I ran idea with-sources=yes.  To get around this issue, I started sbt instead of play.  I then ran the following commands from sbt: "update", "update-classifierss", "update-sbt-classifiers".  This downloaded alot of sources to my local.  After that, I was able to go into the play console and run "idea with-sources=yes" and have it work.  Note: I did not have the same issues on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: You can use the original sbt-idea plugin to avoid having to do post fix-up after running `play idea`. see my answer below!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for that. For some reason, the way I was importing projects into IDEA was throwing errors left and right. Your guide really helped!

Comment: NOTE: When **IDEA can't recognize reverse routes in scala templates**, need to do following: • Open the module settings _(CTRL+ALT+Shift+S)_ • select Modules->myapp->Sources (tab) • add `target\scala-2.10\src_managed\main` as Sources (as shown in this [figure](http://i.imgur.com/cdWANzR.png)) and remove 2 or 3 long paths from sources (they are not in figure)

Comment: Hi @akkie, thanks for your edit. I did this with Intellij and it allows me to go to sources in the IDE, which is great. However, now, when I run `play console` it recompiles everything! Same if I run `play console` first and then run the Play app from within Intellij. Have you run into this issue, or any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Play console includes a fork of a sbt plugin named [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea). The play's fork got a little lagged behind the original plugin, and has some problems in IntelliJ when you run `play idea`. You can use the original plugin, which doesn't have any issues. In order to use this plugin in your play project, you need to..

1.Add the following lines to `project/plugins.sbt` file: (the blank line in the middle is required)

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.1")
```

2.Run `gen-idea` from the play console.

Answer (score 0):

I usually used IntellijIDEA (version 12.0.4) only for Play Framework code editor because of:

1. Auto saving feature by default
2. Rather fast IntelliSense feature
3. Dracula UI, it is an eye-pleasure for me

And I usually run and debug the apps with Play SBT console. It's reasonable fast. But, sometimes when executing `play` command on console, I found that the *loading-project-info* task take too long time (nearly 10 minutes). I don't know why this sometimes happen, but overall the use of Play SBT console is my choice.

I'm doing that because there is usually *should-not-be-the-problem-things* intepreted as *error* like following :

[image: IDEA Error]

The first time when I start learning Play Framework, I was facing such problem. So, at the end, I choose to use Play SBT console to run and debugging app then.

And sorry I cannot answer for the question number 2. Until now I only tried running and debugging play application. For testing purpose I've never tried before for Play 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I take it that you only use IntelliJ as an editor.  Last night, I managed to install the SBT Console in IntelliJ, and I can do things like ~test-only test=xxxSPec in there.  Very nice, and pretty fast from a compilation standpoint.  I agree, the loading project info can take a while, that is why it seemed best to simply have play / sbt console running all the time

Comment: I am leaving the question unanswered for the time being.  I am hoping that someone can respond on whether they actually are able to get better integration between Play and IntelliJ.  Specifically on the exception that I posted.

Comment: +1 Yeah my friend, I also want to put a good attention too for this question!