# How to access external libraries using Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use an external library contained in a .jar file with the Play Framework.

I've added the .jar file to the `lib/` directory, to no avail.

I know I could add the dependency to my `project/Build.scala` file, but I have no idea what the group ID, artifact ID, or version numbers are. Are those found in the .jar file?

Comment: Did you restart PLay! after putting the jar into lib directory?

Comment: I just tried it... didn't work. I have SomeClass.jar in `lib/`, and when I ask for a `new SomeClass()` it says it can't find the type.

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but did you `import` the library? If the library wasn't added to the classpath properly by Play!, the compilation error should come from the import line, not from the instantiation.

Comment: Well, here's an even worse question: What should the `import` look like? When I try `import SomeClass._` it tells me it can't find the object.

Comment: Alos, for what its worth, when I go to the play console, I can look at the classpath and it *is* in there, as it should be

Comment: Should be something like `import com.domain.library._`, where `com.domain.library` is the main package of the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Project Structure
Under Project Setting -> Modules -> 
Go to tab Dependencies , under sbt-unmanaged-jars you can edit and add your lib manually.

Answer (score 0):

`groupID`, `artifactID` and `version` are “[Maven Coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates)”. These three identifies are needed to find exact jar file in the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/). When provided, the build system (and Play! uses SBT) can automatically find, download and include the library you want to use (assuming that that library exists in the repository).

As that is a global repository, `groupID` should uniquely identify the project. `groupID` is usually the same as the main project's package, e.g. `org.apache.commons`. `artifactID` is supposed to identify a particular jar in the project, e.g. `commons-io`. `version`, quite obviously, points to the exact version of the jar.

Comment: Ah, I thought so. So, my `jar` file is definitely not in the Maven Repository (or SBT). Play claims that I can just drop it in `lib/` and it will work... but I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

[How to use IntelliJ with Play Framework and Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135716/how-to-use-intellij-with-play-framework-and-scala) 
see this short tutorial.

but you have to add all necessary jars to lib folder before call create module command `idea with-sources=yes`

So, again

1. Create a new application
2. Create lib folder and copy all jars
3. Create the IDE module

This is only one way how I can deploy it successfully