# IntelliJ IDE does not detect Scala templates properly

Tags: java, scala, playframework, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to get play framework to work properly in IntelliJ but it seems like my Scala templates aren´t detected properly. These are the steps I have done:

Setup:

1. Brew install play
2. Brew install sbt
3. Download and install play Framework plugin for IntelliJ
4. Download and install Scala plugin for IntelliJ
5. Download and install SBT plugin for IntelliJ

From Terminal i run this (in the following order):

1. play new doTest
2. play clean compile
3. play idea
4. sbt
5. gen-idea

In IntelliJ I open the project and check the file
**target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/controllers/routes** and it looks like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/EN4iqux.png]

I have also tried following these instructions step by step to set up a completely fresh installation:

[How to use intellij with play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135716/how-to-use-intellij-with-play-framework-and-scala/)

And after completing all steps, IntelliJ is still unable to resolve the Scala templates. This is from a completely fresh play application:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL9V3.png]

I can compile, run tests from the IDE and watch changes I have made in the browser. The only thing that isn´t working is the code assistance within IntelliJ. I have no idea how to proceed at this point, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally managed to figure it out. It seems like IntelliJ picks up on the compiled Scala templates. Right-clicking on the target folder, and select "Mark Directory As" --> "Excluded" fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ doesn't use the routes file as a source file.  It is aware of the routes, though, so if you do something like routes.Application, it will be able to resolve that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don´t understand where and what to change. I am very new to play framework and feel quite confused at this point. Do you have anything I can read on the subject?