# Intellij doesn't detect Play syntax

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I have IntelliJ community 14.14 installed and Scala plugin 1.5.2.
I have created a play project using `activator new` and I imported it into IntelliJ, but it doesn't recognize the views. I have tried searching all over, but did not find a solution.

When I right click on the project and choose `Add Framework Support` I don't find `Play`. I only find `Maven`, `Groovy`, `Scala`

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577573/intellij-idea-can-not-resolve-symbol-with-play-framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753725/intellij-ide-does-not-detect-scala-templates-properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play framework isn't supported in IntelliJ community edition.You need the ultimate version for that purpose and you can read about it on the [editions comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).