# How to add play Framework to IntelliJ?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

how to add play framework in IntelliJ 13.1 ?I am doing scala project but and i want complete configuration through play framework ,but it is not there in intelliJ by default.

Comment: What version of Play are you using? For < 2.2 have you tried `play idea` command or for 2.3+ `activator idea` and then importing the IntelliJ project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use IntelliJ with Play Framework and Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135716/how-to-use-intellij-with-play-framework-and-scala)